# How can I return an error from a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, return

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
const getPlayer = (id) => {
  return players[id;]
}
//--------------------------
const client = getPlayer(9);
```

How can I return the **err** parameter to the **client** variable if no player is found? For example:

```
if (client.err) { 
//do something
}
```

I tried passing the error via *throw new Error('my error')* , but the function still doesn't get it, what am I doing wrong?:(

Comment: Please, when asking question try to not hurry, review your own posted code for errors. Create a [mcve]. It's not clear what you're after. - After all.

Answer (score 1):

So your first instinct was correct, you should use the 'throw' keyword to raise an error. To *act* on the error you need to use `try/catch` like I've done below.

```
const getPlayer = (id) => {
  if(id in players) {
     return players[id];
  }
  throw new Error("Oh noes...!");
}

try {
   const client = getPlayer(9);
} catch(error) {
   console.log(error.message);
}
```

When an error is thrown inside a function being executed in a `try` block, execution immediately jumps to the catch block, allowing you to respond to the error appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout try/catch syntax for that.

For example:

```
const getPlayer = (id) => { 
    if (!id) {
        throw new Error('no id provided');
    }

    return players[id]
}
```

To get this "error" state, when it triggers you can do following:

```
try {
    const client = getPlayer(null);
} catch(error) {
   console.log(error.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something but not sure if this is what you are after:

```
let a = (x) => {
  if (x == 0) {
    throw new Error("Votes are zero");
  } else {
    return x;
  }
};
```

Run it in the console with the values as a(0) --> will throw you a new error and a(5)